# Generating an array without repeats in angular 2

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, ionic2

I'm, trying to create an array of six, and it must not have any repeating numbers from 1 to 60.

My code right now its like this:

```
 jogar(){        
    if(this.random.length != 0){
        this.random=[];
        }else{
            for(var u=0; u<6; u++){
             this.y = Math.ceil(Math.random()*59+1);
                for (var r of this.random){
                    if(r != this.y){
                        this.random.push(this.y); 
                    };  
                };                                                              
            }; 
            this.random.sort(function(a, b){return a-b});
            return this.random; 
        };                                 
};
```

It should check if the array has more then 0 elements, if it does it'll empty it. 
if it's empty it'll assemble the array...
And it should not repeat numbers...
This works up to the point that I insert the repeating checker..:

```
               for(var r of this.random)
                if(r != this.y){
                    this.random.push(this.y); 
                };
```

This guy makes my code stop working.

After searching I read something about the Fisher-Yates Shuffle technique, but it doesn't seems to work for me.

I'm using angular 2, with the Ionic 2 framework.

Does someone here have come up with this already?

Comment: Where you able to solve this?

Comment: Yes, but not using your method, I'll post my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what my code looks now. Working!

```
jogar(){    
    this.final = [];
    this.numeros = [];  
    for(var i=0;this.final.length<6;i++){
        this.final = this.numberSelect.map(Number).concat(this.numeros);           
        var novoNumero=Math.floor((Math.random()*59)+1);            
        var verificacao=this.confereSeArrayContemItem(this.final,novoNumero);       
        if(verificacao!==1){
            this.numeros.push(novoNumero);                
        }else{
            i--;
        }
        this.final.sort(function(a,b){return a-b});      
    } 
    console.log(this.final.sort(function(a,b){return a-b}));
}

confereSeArrayContemItem(array, item){
    var resultado = 0;
    for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++){
        if(array[i]===item){
            resultado =1;
        }
    }
    return resultado;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That sentence is wrong because

```
for(var r of this.random)
  if(r != this.y){
    this.random.push(this.y); 
};
```

Will try to push the `this.y` number to the random array, each time that a number from the random array is different from the `this.y` number.

As you can see in this [working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/prvDU7?p=preview), you can achieve what you're looking for with the following code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({...})
export class HomePage {

  random: Array<number> = [];


  public jogar(): Array<number> {        
    if(this.random.length != 0) {
      this.random=[];
    }

    while (this.random.length < 6) { // <- Use while instead of for
      let randomNumber = this.getRandomNumber(); // Get a random number
      if(!this.wasAlreadyAdded(randomNumber)) {
        this.random.push(randomNumber); // Add it if it doesn't exist in the array
      }
    }

    this.random.sort(function(a, b){return a-b});
    return this.random; 

  }  

  private getRandomNumber(): number {
    return Math.ceil(Math.random()*59+1);
  }

  private wasAlreadyAdded(randomNumber: number): number {
    return this.random.indexOf(randomNumber) !== -1;
  }

}
```